# How can I redirect all www traffic to non www url in vue project

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following code in my htaccess file which is supposed to redirect all www requests to the non www version of index.html, but its not working and I'm not sure why. Can anyone help?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: When you say "not working" can you give details about the error / problem you are seeing?

Comment: Don't use `%{HTTP_HOST}` in target otherwise it will redirect to same `www.` host name. Capture value after `www.` and use `%1` in target.

Comment: @David. It breaks the site and nothing loads when I leave lines 2 and 3 inside the if block uncommented

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have it like this:

```sh
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L,NC]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

Here we are capturing value after `www.` in a capture group and then using that as `%1` in target URL.

Make sure to clear your browser cache or use a new browser before you test this change.

Comment: I'm sorry I actually uploaded the htaccess file to the wrong site. This does work to fix it!!!